# MySQL Comparison Binary Collation vs Binary Strings

Tags: mysql, types

according to mysql certification guide, comparisons between binary collation vs binary strings are different because comparisons in binary collation is done per character vs per byte in binary strings. but what difference does that give?

Comment: did you pass certification btw?

Answer (score 0):

you can't set collation on binary data ( '01100110101011') - what would be the point of that?
So - no collation for any binary strings: BINARY, VARBINARY, TINYBLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, BLOB. Comparisons for these data types are always done on byte by byte basis.

Default collation for MySQL columns is case-insensitive. It's a regular dictionary collation, ex: latin_swedish_ci, utf8_general_ci (ci - case insensitive). So - your searches are case-insensitive.

You can use binary collation to achieve case-sensitive searches.
There are some other differences also:

[case-senhsitivity](http://venutip.com/content/case-sensitivity-mysql-do-you-really-need-it)